# Symbolically represent values in an array

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, symbolic-math

I have an array that contains fixed constants c's and weights w's. It looks something like:

[image]

I'm trying to solve for the weights *w*'s while (1) fixing the constants *c*'s
and (2) making sure the row sums are 1 (`X.sum(axis=1) = [1, 1, 1, 1]`).

Is there a programmatic way to symbollically represent certain entries (ie. set w_{b} at rows={0, 1, 2}, cols={2, 3}), and then solve for these symbolic representations? Note that this is different from solving a systems of linear equations.

Comment: I don't know, but have you looked into sympy? https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/numeric-computation.html

Comment: Did you try [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html)?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of Sympy - but perhaps I forgot to ask this explicitly: how do I go about solving for these symbolic representations? It's not obvious how to define a cost function and do gradient descent to approximate the best weights while holding specific values constant.

Comment: The representation of the values in an array is not relevant to what you are trying to do.  You appear to have a set of 4 linear equations.  This is easily solvable with as an LP with a math solver.  However, solutions won't likely be unique because you have 5 unknowns.  Have you used a math solver before?  `pyomo`, `pulp`, `or-tools` ?